# Anchor tags in URL not working in Flask Website

Tags: html, flask, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap template for user-profile settings where I have two forms; update user info and update password. Each of these forms is wrapped in a div with unique id's that can be anchored with #account-general and #account-change-password. when I click on change password, it brings me to that section of the page, indicating that the anchor links are working correctly.

The problem is that whenever I try to change the password and there is an error, it redirects me back to the account-general section, not the change-password section even if the anchor is in the link.
[Here is a link to the template for a better visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6DeR.png)

I tried changing the browser from chrome to edge b/c I read that there were might be problems with anchor tags in chrome. I Also played around with different ways to add an anchor tag with url_for.
Here is the route and function.

```
@views.route('user-profile/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    id=current_user.id
    user = User.query.get_or_404(id)
    update_user = Update_userinfo()
    update_password=Update_Password()
    if request.method =='POST':
        if update_user.validate_on_submit():
            if not update_user.errors:
                if User.query.filter_by(email=update_user.email.data).first(): 
                    if update_user.email.data == user.email:
                        user.firstname = update_user.firstname.data
                        user.lastname = update_user.lastname.data
                        user.email = update_user.email.data
                        db.session.commit()
                        flash("user info updated sucsessfully!", category="success")
                        return redirect(url_for('views.dashboard'))
                    else:
                        flash("This email is already in our database!", category="error")
                else:
                    user.firstname = update_user.firstname.data
                    user.lastname = update_user.lastname.data
                    user.email = update_user.email.data
                    db.session.commit()
                    flash("user info updated sucsessfully!", category="success")
                    return redirect(url_for('views.dashboard'))
            else:
                flash_errors(update_user)
           
        if update_password.validate_on_submit():
            if check_password_hash(user.password, update_password.old_password.data):
                hashed_pw = generate_password_hash(update_password.new_password.data, method="sha256")
                user.password = hashed_pw
                db.session.commit()

                

                # msg  = Message('Your password was changed', recipients=[user.email])
                # msg.body = 'Hey ' + user.firstname + ', your password was recently updated. If this was you, please feel free to ignore this email. If you did not update your password, contact us right away at something@emailaddres.com.'
                # mail.send(msg)

                flash('password changed Sucsessfully!', category='success')
                return redirect(url_for('views.dashboard'))
            else:
             **   flash("Wrong password! Try Again", category='error')
                return redirect(url_for("views.dashboard", _anchor ="account-change-password") )
        else:
            flash_errors(update_password) 
            return redirect(url_for("views.dashboard", _anchor ="account-change-password")) **

    return render_template('dashboard.html', update_user=update_user, user=user, update_password=update_password)
```

As You can see here, I used the anchor parameter to add it to the the url and that part works fine.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container light-style flex-grow-1 container-p-y">

    <h4 class="font-weight-bold py-3 mb-4">
      Account settings
    </h4>

    <div class="card overflow-hidden">
      <div class="row no-gutters row-bordered row-border-light">
        <div class="col-md-3 pt-0">
          <div class="list-group list-group-flush account-settings-links">
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="list" href="#account-general">General Settings</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#account-change-password">Change password</a>
            <!-- <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#account-info">Info</a> -->
            <!-- <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#account-social-links">Social links</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#account-connections">Connections</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#account-notifications">Notifications</a> -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="tab-content">


            <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="account-general">

              <div class="card-body media align-items-center">
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile pic.png')}}" alt="" class="d-block ui-w-80">
                <div class="media-body ml-4">
                  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                    Upload new photo
                    <input type="file" class="account-settings-fileinput">
                  </label> &nbsp;
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default md-btn-flat">Reset</button>

                  <div class="text-light small mt-1">Allowed JPG, GIF or PNG. Max size of 800K</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr class="border-light m-0">

              <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ update_user.hidden_tag() }}
                  {{ update_user.firstname.label(class="form-label") }}
                  {{ update_user.firstname(class="form-control", value=user.firstname) }}
            
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ update_user.lastname.label(class="form-label") }}
                  {{ update_user.lastname(class="form-control", value=user.lastname) }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ update_user.email.label(class="form-label") }}
                  {{ update_user.email(class="form-control", value=user.email) }}
                </div>
          
                <div class="text-right mt-3">
                {{update_user.submit(class="btn btn-secondary")}}
              </form>
                
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="account-change-password">
              <div class="card-body pb-2">
                <form method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ update_password.hidden_tag() }}

                    {{ update_password.old_password.label(class="form-label") }}
                    {{update_password.old_password(class="form-control")}}

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ update_password.new_password.label(class="form-label") }}
                  {{update_password.new_password(class="form-control")}}
                 
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ update_password.new_password2.label(class="form-label") }}
                  {{update_password.new_password2(class="form-control")}}
                  
              
                </div>
                <div class="text-right mt-3">
                  {{update_password.submit(class="btn btn-secondary")}}

                </form>
                  
                  </div>

              </div>
            </div>
```